# HTTP POST request error 400 in Java Servlet

Tags: tomcat, http-post

I have a web application that interacts with a DB via a Java Servlet using HTTP-Post requests (initially used GET but the length of the requests forced me to switch to the POST method).

I'm getting a 400 status and can't find the reason:

1. I'm issuing several different requests to the DB, all work fine till I reached a large one (12K JSON string) which is preventing me from proceeding,
2. I checked the structure of the JSON and it looks OK (I'm using this [great site](https://jsonlint.com/)).

The DB properly handles the received JSON when invoked within the DB.

Logs files (TOMCAT) do not show anything specific.

How can I find what the problem could be? Right now I don't even know what to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. There was an error message within one of TOMCAT's logs that I missed claiming that the size of the header was too big. I simply changed the configuration of tomcat (`server.xml`) to:

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="200000"
           maxPostSize="0"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

[note the max size of the header]

Comment: What log was it in?  I am seeing 400 errors, but no explanation as to why they are happening